# Deb build-dependencies in custom locations

Tags: debian, apt, deb, node.js, npm

I have a debian package with `npm` build dependency, e.g, the control file contains the line:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 11), npm
```

Building this package works fine if I have installed `nodejs` using `apt-get`, which creates the file `/usr/bin/npm`. The problem is that on my current system I have installed nodejs using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), which installs everything to the home folder and adds the `~.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin` folder to `PATH`. Now when trying to build the debian package, I get:

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: npm
```

even though the `npm` command works when used in the shell. Is there a way to use binaries installed to the home folder to satisfy the build dependencies?

Comment: Hopefully not. If there should be any sense in declaring a build dependency on npm, the package must build with what's installed by npm, and not something that might be available in *your* path.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the build-dependency check using `dpkg-buildpackage`’s `-d` option:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -d
```

Whether that ends up using your locally-installed `npm` binary will depend on the details of the build system, but I think it should do so.

The result might not match what the package maintainer intended, but if anything breaks, you’ll still have all the pieces...